# How to use url encoded data in get method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, urlencode, restful-url, cfurl-encoding

I am working on a restful service in asp.net `MVC 4 Web API`. I have a get method that getting a url encoded data as a parameter from URI. But, the thing is when I try this method from `RESTClient` (firefox tool), I am getting 404. And when i check the stack trace my url seems with non encoded parameter. You can see the example below:

```
Url format: /api/Applications/key
```

I am sending this:

```
/api/Applications/3baxYhYzpVGTrIIzs4CvGv4KIcIRHn5yqx%2F9a5PzTJxK4SWVcwi9GI6bib9pe1psk%2FdYeD0EaOdMHZpzWl%2Fbwg%3D%3D
```

In the response body, request url seems like this;

```
/api/Applications/3baxYhYzpVGTrIIzs4CvGv4KIcIRHn5yqx/9a5PzTJxK4SWVcwi9GI6bib9pe1psk/dYeD0EaOdMHZpzWl/bwg==
```

I am getting an error because of escape characters. I can use post but I want to go on with restful architecture.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Post your controller method

Comment: Hi @matt,Sadly i didn't find any other solution, and i am doing post for this type methods.